# Converting a JavaScript Countdown to a jQuery Countdown and adding an Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found [this JS-Countdown Script](http://jsfiddle.net/XcvaE/4/') at JSFiddle.

EDIT:

I'm using the code of `rafaelcastrocouto` now, which is nearly perfect. I wanted a 10-seconds JQuery Countdown-Script with an interval that resets the countdown timer at 5 seconds and starts over again and again, but only **for a specific class with a specific** **id** on the whole HTML page. If it drops to 0, the countdown should stop. Also I want to reset **specific** counters to 10.

It's about a WebSocket that refreshes every second and depending on the data I get for specific counters I want to reset them or they should count down to zero.

New JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexiovay/azkdry0w/4/

Comment: Please can you create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this, show how you initialize your `loop` function including adding example html.

Comment: And `.attr("data-something")` is better accessed using `.data("something")` assuming it is useful to set it in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved with jquery and native **setInterval**...

```js
var setup = function(){
  $('.count').each(eachSetup);    
};

var eachSetup = function(){
  var count = $(this);
  var sec = count.data('seconds') ;  
  count.data('count', sec);
};

var everySecond = function(){  
  $('.count').each(eachCount);    
};

var eachCount = function(){
  var count = $(this);
  var s = count.data('count');
  count.text(s);
  s--;
  if(s < 0) { 
    s = count.data('seconds');
  }
  count.data('count', s);
};

setup();
setInterval(everySecond, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count" data-seconds="5"></p>
<p class="count" data-seconds="10"></p>
<p class="count" data-seconds="15"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I change only one specific counter? They all should stop at 0. And specific counters should also reset at a specific given time I want to set working with a WebSocket. That's what I want to realize.

Comment: keep trying (use [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tebeyiviji/1/edit?html,js,output)) and if you hit a problem just raise another question ok?

Answer (score 0):

You have sever errors in code, e.g.

1. `setTimeout(cd_go(id), 1000);` - should point to function reference not to function execution. setTimeout also returns the timeout **id**. You must past that `id` to clearTimeout
2. `clearTimeout(this);` it should take **id** instead of global object (window) or undefined if you are working in **strict mode**
3. `loop = setInterval(function(id) { … }` - **id** points to **undefinded** as you are not passing any value for it